# Unknown Colum in Update Statement for Column that is not in query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to update my table. My query is

```
'UPDATE mainOrderData SET isInvoiced = ?, invoiceCw = ? WHERE id = ?' 

with params [1, "15", 17408]
```

That query is from Symfony / Doctrine. But I've already tried many variations of that, the error is *not* simply a typo or syntax error. It occurs no matter how I feed the sql into the database, it's something to do with the structure of the database.

I always get the error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'MainOrderId'
>   in 'where clause'

Now the curious thing is - I never specified MainOrderId. I specified id, and that column exists and is the right one.

How the hell does my database change that query?

Here's my server info:

MySQL
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server Version: 5.5.59
Protokoll-Version: 10
Benutzer: 
MySQL-Zeichensatz: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Apache
MySQL-Client-Version: mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id:  $
PHP Erweiterung: mysql

My code is pretty boilerplate:

```
$mainOrderData = $em->getRepository(MainOrderData::class)->find($id);
$woche = date("W");
$mainOrderData->isInvoiced = 1;
$mainOrderData->invoiceCw = $woche;
$em->flush();
```

I've no relations in the entities, and no triggers postupdate or somesuch defined. The entity in question does not hava a MainOrderId, only other entities that are not connected to the object manipulated.

The same thing happens if I use a manual sql query - **any reference to id will be changed to MainOrderId.**

Comment: show  also the code you are using not only a resume ..

Comment: This could happen if you have a trigger on the table.

Comment: ... or from the Doctrine entity what you have defined.. Hard to say without seeing code..

Comment: How would I go about looking for triggers? In my phpMyAdmin I see nothing of the sort.

Comment: are you alter your table or not?

Comment: Thanks, Gordon Linoff, I finally found the culprit. It was a hidden trigger that was not displayed, and there a column name was different.
Never would have found it, since it was hidden. Thanks for the help!

For anyone wondering: in my old phpMyAdmin-Version (only thing I got access to), you had to click  "details" on the structure tab of the table, otherwise triggers would not show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could happen if you have a trigger on the table. – Gordon Linoff 19 mins ago

That was it, the triggers were hidden and I had no idea they were there. The error message was unhelpful, too.

Thanks, Gordon Linoff!